# How can I tweak text's vertical alignment to correct for a font's misalignment?

Tags: css

Lets say I have a font that's incorrectly centered vertically so that even with these styles Example 1 and 2 render above the center of the element:

```css
div {
  padding: 0.1in;
  background-color: #6C6ECC;
  color: white;
  margin: 0.1in;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:Arial;
}

.tweak {
  vertical-align:-0.1in;
}
```

```html
<div class="basis">EXAMPLE 1</div>
<div class="tweak">EXAMPLE 2</div>
```

In this example, they're both properly centered, but my goal is for Example 2's text to be below the vertical center of the element, while everything else about the elements remains visually the same. I want to correct a font's incorrect vertical alignment (the font just naturally renders off-center, above the center of normal text lines).

Comment: Can you explain it propery , an expected image??

Comment: i got it @curiosity5678

Answer (score 1):

If you know the text will be just one line, you can use a combination of `height` and `line-height`. Otherwise you will need something like `position: relative; top: -4px` (but that would move the colored background in your example as well, so you'd need a wrapping element)

```css
div {
  padding: 0.1in;
  background-color: #6C6ECC;
  color: white;
  margin: 0.1in;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:Arial;
}

.tweak {
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
.tweak2 {
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="basis">EXAMPLE 1</div>
<div class="tweak">EXAMPLE 2</div>
<div class="tweak2">EXAMPLE 3</div>
```